# Issues with gorilla/csrf

Tags: javascript, jquery, go, gorilla

So, for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get gorilla's csrf to work when not injecting it straight into fields. It keeps talking about passing it through headers and cookies, but nothing I do seems to work... here's what I have for my go server:

`

```
package main
import (
    "gorilla/mux"
    "gorilla/csrf"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "http/template"
    "time"
)

func showLoginPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Set-Cookie", "_gorilla_csrf="+csrf.Token(r))
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "<template_here>", nil)
}


func doLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Set-Cookie", "_gorilla_csrf="+csrf.Token(r))
    /**
    builds resp
    **/
    w.Write(resp)
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/login", showLoginPage).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/login", doLogin).Methods("POST")
    r.PathPrefix("/js/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/js/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./js"))))
    r.PathPrefix("/css/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css"))))

    srv := &http.Server{
          Handler:      csrf.Protect([]byte("very-secret-string"), csrf.Secure(false))(r),
          Addr:         "127.0.0.1:8000",
          // Good practice: enforce timeouts for servers you create!
          WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
          ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}
```

`

whereas, on my frontend I have this so that all requests get updated:
`

```
var getCookie = function(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  return "";
};
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) {
    options.beforeSend = function (xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', getCookie('_gorilla_csrf'));
    }
});
```

`

I know I have to be missing something, but I really just can't seem to grasp this at all. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're overwriting the gorilla created real CSRF token using this line. Gorilla is using session store to keep real CSRF tokens for validation.

```
w.Header().Set("Set-Cookie", "_gorilla_csrf="+csrf.Token(r))
```

Please do not touch `_gorilla_csrf` this cookie.

Gorilla supports the CSRF via `form field` and `header` only. So pick your choice, their [readme](https://github.com/gorilla/csrf/blob/master/README.md) has required information you need (Form field, Header and Customizing field name & header name).

`gorilla/csrf` checks CSRF token in this order:

> gorilla/csrf inspects the HTTP headers (first) and form body (second) on subsequent POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE/etc. requests for the token.

Comment: So, for whatever reason (maybe I had changed something without realizing it) - but after I did what you said I'm actually getting back the correct _gorilla_csrf - it wasn't coming through before. That being said, I'm still getting 403 forbiddens when setting the X-CSRF-Token header to the value returned by getCookie, any idea why?

Comment: @ReginadScarr Good to hear, you're getting the correct `_gorilla_csrf` cookie. You can accept the answer, I believe.

Comment: So, it looks like i'm not actually getting the right key... it sends back the same thing, every time, without fail. I'm at a loss as what to do here.

Comment: That's strange. Okay let me give it try at my end and let you know.

Comment: I have tried the sample code from gorilla pkg, it works perfectly. For your reference https://play.golang.org/p/jVKR7dtPrV